# How to extract variable in the browser with %3f %3d

Tags: php, html, web-services, browser

I'm redirecting my page to another page and when I went to the result, it don't show up the data.

When I check my browser it showing variables like this

```
itemid=537600240%3fusername%3d&
```

I need to extract `itemid=537600240` but when I tried to do it it goes up to 
`itemid=537600240?fusername`.

I just need value before the ? or %3f. Need help please

Comment: Please post the code that does the extraction

Answer (score 0):

get the whole value that is itemid=537600240?fusername and use explode function to get the value before the ? sign.

Answer (score 0):

i think theres something wrong when you concatinate values in header link

it should be

```
http:/mypage/index.php?id=$id&name=$name
```

to get the values

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$name=$_GET['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're building your redirect URL incorrectly. The proper URI and Query String format should be:

```
http://domain.com/dir/script.php?var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=baz
```

Where `?` occurs only *once* to delimit the end of the path portion of the URI and the beginning of the query string. `&` should be used to separate the individual query variables.

`%3f` is a urlencoded `?` and `%3d` is a urlencoded `=` which I assume your browser is doing to try and make your broken URL into a sane one.

Additionally, any time you need to include data that might itself contain a special character like `?`, `&`, `=`, `#`, etc you should first pass that data through `urlencode()` before appending it to the query string so that you do not encounter unexpected behaviour.

Anyhow, once you fix this you should get the proper values in `$_GET` and not have to do any extra processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
<?php

    $var = 'itemid=537600240%3fusername%3d& ';

    $regex = '/itemid=[0-9]+/';

    preg_match ( $regex, $var, $result);

    echo $result[0];

?>
```

Test it online: http://ideone.com/SMho8e

Or, if you want just the integer value, change the regex and the result as follows:

```
<?php

    $var = 'itemid=537600240%3fusername%3d& ';

    $regex = '/itemid=([0-9]+)/';

    preg_match ( $regex, $var, $result);

    echo $result[1];

?>
```

Test it online: http://ideone.com/AIIna8